# multi line chart nvd3 not shown properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to show a many line charts in one chart.

What's happening is that, instead of showing them all at the same time, you need to disable one to show another one.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7B9t/3/)`;`
What do I need to change in my code so it shows all of the graphs together?

Thanks folks

Comment: do you want all the lines to show on one chart, or do you want small-multiples/facets type charts?

Comment: I want all lines to show on one chart. If you put my jsfiddle code to nvd3 live code website it behaves correctly by showing all the graphs in one chart. EDIT : I managed to have it working by including the d3.v2.js as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try not to give the same `Key names`** for your charts. NVD3 by default merges the duplicate Key names together.

After I changed the Key Name from you chart it seems to pick All the line charts correctly.

Here is a Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/rgg7t/) of your code

Hope it helps.